# randomly allocate an Item to a list

Tags: list, indexing, insert

Here I have a simple program that removes and inserts into the list. Right now I can only figure out how to do it using the index position and the remove and insert methods, but I can't figure out how to insert into the list at any index randomly.

```
animals=['a','b','c','d','e']

while True:
    print("Press 'h' to randomly place animal into a spot on list: ")
    answer=input("what would you like to do?: ")
    if answer=="h":
        askfor=input("Name the animal to insert: ")
        animals.remove('a')
        n=animals.insert(0, askfor)
        print(animals)
    else:
        print("Invalid value. Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `randomint` method of the `random` library https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

So

```
import random
animals=['a','b','c','d','e']

while True:
    print("Press 'h' to randomly place animal into a spot on list: ")
    answer=input("what would you like to do?: ")
    if answer=="h":
        askfor=input("Name the animal to insert: ")
        animals.remove('a')
        #n=animals.insert(0, askfor)
        animals.insert(random.randint(0, len(animals)-1), askfor)
        print(animals) 
    else:
        print("Invalid value. Try again")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped. Is there a way to remove a random item and replace the one removed with the one you want to insert?

Comment: Surely, but can you ask a different question for that? It's hard to answer in just a comment. If that's too much of a hassle, then I'll just say you can use https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp to delete the value at the random index and then add the new value at that same random index. Remember that if the random index was the last value of animals, you need to append the new value to animals instead of insert.